# DataLoaderOptions.AutoDispatch in hotchocolate v11

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, hotchocolate

I'm trying to migrate HotChocolate from v10 to v11, and facing a unit test problem.
In order to test a dataloader load, I had this code which was working fine.

```
var loader = new CompanySettingDataLoader(api, new DataLoaderOptions<string>
{
    AutoDispatching = true
});

var result = await loader.LoadAsync("Param2", CancellationToken.None);
```

In the v11 migration guide I found that I should migrate to this syntax but AutoDispatch does not exists anymore in DataLoaderOptions, so my DataLoader never triggers, and my test locks the binaries.

```
var scheduler = new BatchScheduler();

var loader = new CompanySettingDataLoader(scheduler, api, new DataLoaderOptions<string>
{
    // here ?
});

var result = await loader.LoadAsync("Param2", CancellationToken.None);
```

As hotchocolate documentation is poor and migration guide not complete, does somebody has an idea of what I'm missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```cs
var scheduler = new AutoBatchScheduler();

var loader = new CompanySettingDataLoader(scheduler, api);

var result = await loader.LoadAsync("Param2", CancellationToken.None);
```